# How can I start a jupyter notebook instance with customised import context?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing a plugin to enhance Flask shell with bpython ipython and jupyter notebook like Django Extensions do. But I did not find a good way to start a jupyter notebook instance with imported context just like I've implemented with shell/bpython/ipython.

So, my question is how can I start a notebook instance with customised context easy like `NotebookApp.instance.start(context=context)`?

Comment: There isn't an easy way, because user code runs in separate 'kernel' processes, not in the notebook server application.

Comment: @ThomasK Seems so it is. Maybe the only way to do this is defining a notebook extension and create an new kernel based on it just like Django Extensions do.